# Data transfer with databases (selected tables data only)

Tags: azure-sql-database

in azure sql/sql how to transfer selected tables data between databases automatically.....we have bacpac option but i need only selected tables data to move .. if bacbac deploy the schema and data do that data or schema over right the target database if it already exist .....for example i have a bacpac of 100 tables (schema and data) if i deploy this bacpac in target database where already 50 tables are existing including(schema and data ) how does this work

Comment: You can achieve this `Using SQL Server Export/Import wizard` or you only want to use bacpac file to achieve this?. Please share what you have tried and error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server Management Studio tool, **`SQL Server Export and Import wizard`**, is accessible. In order to transfer the data.

- launch SQL Server Management Studio and login to your server.
- Right-click on the Source Database and select Tasks > Export Data.
  [image]
- To continue, launch the Import/Export Wizard and click Next.
- Enter the data source, server name, authentication method, and source database. Next, click.
  [image]
- Enter the destination, server name, authentication method, and destination database now, and then click Next.
  [image]
- In the following window, select 'Copy data from one or more tables or views' and then click Next.
  [image]
- On the following page, the user must select the tables to be copied from the selected source database to the destination database. Next, click.
  [image]
- To proceed, click Next, and then Finish to exit the wizard.
  [image]
  Following completion, a status report will be created, and a message congratulating the successful execution will be shown.
  [image]